# Sci Fi book female character named Thayne

Tags: story-identification, novel

I am looking for the title of a book written before 1962 that had a female character by the name of Thayne (or some spelling variation of that). Had to do with an planet ruled by amazon women or something along that line.

Comment: Hi Thayne! Welcome to the site. :) Do you remember any of the plot points, or just the Amazon setting? Also, can you confirm what language it was written in? (There's some more advice [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) to help you get answers, and you can also check out the [tour]. :)

Comment: Hi, no I never read the book. I was told that I was named after a character in this book, she was the leader of these amazon women who ruled the planet and men were their slaves. I never lived up to my namesake lol but I just want to know if this book and character really existed or was is just a bs line that I was given as to how I ended up with a boy's name. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: it's not a great match, but it's the closest I've found so far.

It's just possible this might be [*The Star of Life*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?9582) (1952) by Edmond Hamilton.  The deuteragonist - sometime foil and sometime potential love interest - of the hero is **Thayn Marden** (note no "e") who is a leader of the overclass/super race Vramen.  (She is described as "one of the highest-ranking scientists" of a class that consists mostly of scientists.)

It does not match, however in that while the planet (Earth, and others of the "Federated Suns" they visit, like the prison planet of Spica) are essentially under the control of the Vramen, they are not enslaved, and the Vramen are neither primarily warriors nor only women.